# UIPageViewController back swipe is not showing last ViewController. It reloads again

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios7, uiviewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

Im working on UIPageViewController and i'm new to this concept. My requirement is like this,

I have four layouts call it L1, L2, L3 and L4. All the layout design is done in same view controller call it **JLayoutOneVc** My functionality is like magazine so on right/forward swipe we see new article and on left/back swipe i see last loaded article.

- While doing right/forward swipe i call the API which will give me data based on which i decide which layout to display
- Swiping right/forward works fine and shows the data perfect but swiping left/back doesn't show the last loaded screen.

**My code**

```
// load previous Article
-(UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    if ([self.cachedLayouts count] > 0) {
        JLayoutOneVC *prev = (JLayoutOneVC *)[self.cachedLayouts lastObject];
        //[prev setArticleDetailsRespDict:self.articleDetailsRespDict];
        pageCount -= 1;
        return prev;
    }

    JLayoutOneVC *prev = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LayoutOneId"];
    [prev setArticleDetailsRespDict:self.articleDetailsRespDict];
    prev.articleDetailsRespDict = nil;
    [prev.articleDetailsTable reloadData];
    pageCount -= 1;
    return prev;
}

// load next Article
-(UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    JLayoutOneVC *next = (JLayoutOneVC *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LayoutOneId"];
    [next setArticleDetailsRespDict:self.articleDetailsRespDict];
    next.articleDetailsRespDict = nil;
    [next.articleDetailsTable reloadData];
    pageCount += 1;
    return next;
}

- (void)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController willTransitionToViewControllers:(NSArray *)pendingViewControllers
{
    if([pendingViewControllers count]>0)
    {
        // Doing this for testing purpose
        if (self.layout > 4) {
            self.layout = 1;
        } else {
            self.layout += 1;
        }
        [self performSelector:@selector(getArticleDetailsFromServer:) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0f];
    }

}
```

For reference i'm adding images.

- ***Consider this as my first Article.***

[image]

- ***On Right/forward swipe i see***

[image]

- ***This is second article.***

[image]

- ***Now when i swipe back/left this is the issue i'm facind. Instead of loading last ViewController it shows new data.***

[image]

[image]

**Hope you guys will help me out. thanks in advance. Please any doubts in my question comment below.**

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you do the check

```
if ([self.cachedLayouts count] > 0) {
```

Your validation should be based on pageCount:

```
-(UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    if (pageCount > 0) {
        pageCount -= 1;
        JLayoutOneVC *prev = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LayoutOneId"];
        // I'm not sure how setArticleDetailsRespDict get the data, the best way would be get the data base on index, in this example pageCount
        [prev setArticleDetailsRespDict:self.articleDetailsRespDict];
        prev.articleDetailsRespDict = nil;
        [prev.articleDetailsTable reloadData];

        return prev;
    }
}
```

The other method `viewControllerAfterViewController:` should check the pageCount value as well:

```
if (pageCount < MAXPAGECOUNT) {
```

The good way is to add to the custom view controller (JLayoutOneVC) property like for example index and in both of that method you can get this value and increase/decrease it (depend on the method). After that you can just get the data base on that index and reload the view.

Comment: Hey Greg, i have made changes you suggested still no luck. For reference you can try out this app. I need swipe of articles similar to this app https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/the-times-of-india/id427589329?mt=8

Comment: I believe the issue is your data, the way how setArticleDetailsRespDict: method works. Can you log your data every time you change the page and see if it returns the right values. It would help if you could show that method. Also you set that dict: setArticleDetailsRespDict and after that you set up nil: prev.articleDetailsRespDict and you reload the data. So I believe you reload the data with nil dictionary.